# How do I stop duplicate content from appearing in my view when using laravel and ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, validation

Here is my view(Ajax)

```
                $('#basicInfoForm').submit(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        let formData = new FormData(this);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "{{route('profile.basic_info')}}",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: formData,
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            beforeSend:function(){
                                $("#fountainG").fadeIn(1000);
                            },
                            success: function(response){
                               $.each(response.errors, function (key, value) { 
                                 $("#fountainG").fadeOut(1000);
                                 $('.alert-danger').fadeIn(2000);
                                 $('.alert-danger').append('<span>'+value+'</span>'+'<br>');
                                 setTimeout(function() {
                                    $('.alert-danger').fadeOut(4000, 'swing');
                                }, 3000);
                                 
                               });
                            },
                            error: function(data){
                                iziToast.error({
                                title: 'Upload Error',
                                message: data.avatar,
                                position: 'topRight'
                            });
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

And, here is my controller

```
    public function updateBasicInformation(Request $request)
    {
        $basic_info = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'fullname' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
            'phone_number' => 'required|numeric|min:10',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
            'country' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
        ], [
            'phone_number.min' => "The phone number must be at least 10 digits",
        ]);

        if($basic_info->fails())
        {
            return response()->json([
                'errors'=> $basic_info->errors()->all()
            ]);
        }
    }
```

So, basically, there is form with the ID:

```
basicInfoForm
```

and the div with the class `-alert-danger` displays the error. But when I submit the form more than once, it keeps on duplicating the errors even the ones that have been properly validated.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU6m2.png)

How do I get around this, please?

I tried changing the `dataType` to `json` but it didn't make any difference.

I am new to Ajax and Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each submit clear all the errors from UI:

```
$('#basicInfoForm').submit(function(e){

e.preventDefault();

$('.alert-danger').remove();

// ...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

on every submit call you are appending errors and not clearing previous error.
you can do this to fix this.

remove previous error div from DOM and append new error div on AJAX success.

```js
success: function(response){

        $('.alert-danger').remove();

        $.each(response.errors, function (key, value) { 
        //

    }
```